# How to access dynamic field in an object in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-redux

I have implemented form validation using a custom hook where it sends errors as objects to form in the below format.

```
errors : {
    userEmail: {
        required: true
    }
}
```

And the form component as below

```
import React from 'react';

import { FormInput } from './../FormInput/FormInput.component';
import { useFormValidation } from './../../shared/utils/useFormValidation';
import { Button } from './../Button/Button.component';

import './SignIn.styles.css';

import FormFieldsData from './../../shared/data/form-fields';

const SignIn = () => {

    // FORM INITIAL STATE

    const formInitialState = {
        userEmail: '',
        userPassword: ''
    };

    // SETTING VALIDATION RULES FOR FORM FIELDS

    const fieldValidationRules = {
        userEmail: { required: true, isValidEmail: true },
        userPassword: { required: true}
    };

    // INITIALIZING FORM USING HOOK

    const [
        signInFormState,
        errors,
        isValid,
        handleInputChange,
        handleFormSubmit,
        handleBlur
    ] = useFormValidation(formInitialState, fieldValidationRules);

    console.log(errors.userEmail.required);

    const { userEmail, userPassword } = signInFormState;

    return(
        <div className = 'SignInSection'>

            <h1> Sign In here..!! </h1>

            <form onSubmit = {handleFormSubmit} >

                <FormInput 
                    {...FormFieldsData.userEmail}
                    value = {userEmail} 
                    clicked = {handleInputChange}
                    blur = {handleBlur} />

                    {/* Validation Error Message */}

                    

                <FormInput 
                    {...FormFieldsData.userPassword}
                    value = {userPassword}
                    clicked = {handleInputChange}
                    blur = {handleBlur} />
                
                <Button
                    type = 'submit'
                    btn_label = 'Login'
                    btn_size = 'sm'
                    disabled = {!isValid}
                    btn_bg = '#00ACEE'
                    btn_color = '#FFFFFF' />

                <Button
                    type = 'button'
                    btn_label = 'Cancel'
                    btn_size = 'sm'
                    btn_bg = '#4b4b4b'
                    btn_color = '#FFFFFF' />

            </form>

        </div>
    )
};

export { SignIn }
```

When trying to access the required field from error object to implement a Validation Message, I am getting the following error. [image]

Please guide me on how to achieve this functionality?

;

Comment: The error means that the value of `errors.userEmail` is `undefined`. So it looks like you are not receiving the data you expect to get. Either code defensively and verify that the property exists before you try to access a "subproperty", or fix the callsite so that it always passes a "complete" object.

Comment: Form component receiving the data as expected. errors.userEmail will be added to the data object dynamically when there is an validation error

Comment: *"errors.userEmail will be added to the data object dynamically when there is an validation error"* Then I guess you getting this error means that there is no validation error, hence `errors.userEmail` does not exist. You cannot log something (`console.log(errors.userEmail.required)`) that doesn't exist. Not sure what kind of help you expect from us...

Comment: Yeah! I got it. I just console.log it to debug. Actually what i need to implement is {errors.userEmail.required ? ''ERROR MESSAGE' : null}. Also I am getting the same error as above

Comment: Then you have to code defensively: `{errors && errros.userEmail && errors.userEmail.required ? .... : null}`.

Comment: Thanks Felix! It solved the issue

Comment: @FelixKling You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for that now: `errors?.userEmail?.required || null`

Comment: just an fyi, you can use optional chaining too:
```errors?.userEmail?.required```